# Assign multiple values to variable with combination of local variable and variable from property file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to assign values from one local variable and variable value from config properties.

Ex: I want to get output for `$FILE_NAME` as `PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)` where `$FILE_NAME` gets value from variable `$SENDER_BPID` and string `_PROD_FILE_NAME` which make variable in config properties.

If I keep `FILE_NAME=${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}` which has static value (`ADP6`) but I want to use value from variable `SENDER_BPID`.

`FILE_NAME=${$SENDER_BPID"_PROD_FILE_NAME"}` does not work and it gives error as `${$SENDER_BPID"_PROD_FILE_NAME"}: bad substitution`.

Can you please provide me some guideline? Thank you.

**Test.sh**

```
#Load configuration
. /Config.properties

SENDER_BPID=`pwd |awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'`
echo "Sender BPID is $SENDER_BPID"
#SENDER_BPID value is ADP6

FILE_NAME=${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}
echo "Input prod file name is: $FILE_NAME"
```

**Config.properties**

```
ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME='PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)'
```

Comment: @markp-fuso It does not take value from config properties. It shows `Input prod file name is: ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my host:

```
$ . ./Config.properties                          # define variable "ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME"
$ echo "${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}"
PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)
$ SENDER_BPID='ADP6'                             # result of 'pwd|awk'
$ FILE_NAME="${SENDER_BPID}_PROD_FILE_NAME"      # build name of variable
$ echo "${FILE_NAME}"                            # display name of variable
ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME
$ echo "${!FILE_NAME}"                           # display value of variable "ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME"
PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)
```

The following also works (and is what I pushed to the fiddle site):

```
$ ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME='PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)'       # from the Config.properties file
$ echo "${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}"
PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)
$ SENDER_BPID='ADP6'                             # result of 'pwd|awk'
$ FILE_NAME="${SENDER_BPID}_PROD_FILE_NAME"      # build name of variable
$ echo "${FILE_NAME}"                            # display name of variable
ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME
$ echo "${!FILE_NAME}"                           # display value of variable "ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME"
PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)
```

Here's a [bash fiddle](http://tpcg.io/hewl3PiJ) of the above.

Comment: `echo "${FILE_NAME}" ` gives correct result as you mentioned but does not pull value from config properties through `echo "${!FILE_NAME}"`

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 4.2.46

Comment: I'm running GNU bash version 4.4.12(3); hmmm, I'm not sure when indirect variable support became available

Comment: If I use `FILE_NAME=${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}`, it gives me correct result. So, config properties is defined correctly.

Comment: can you double check the contents of `${SENDER_BPID}` and `${FILE_NAME}` ... it is **ADP6**, right?

Comment: As per your bash fiddle, `ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME` defined locally, not in config properties file.

Comment: As per your answer: `echo "${FILE_NAME}"` gives `ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME` and `echo "${!FILE_NAME}"` is blank.

Comment: on my host I created `Config.properties` just like you have it, sourced the file, and the rest is the same (as above), and final result is 'PADPCD.BCL.ADP6(0)'; not sure how to create a temp file on the fiddle site ...

Comment: in your script, right after you source `/Config.properties`, what does `echo "${ADP6_PROD_FILE_NAME}"` show? is `Config.properties` really under the root (`/`) directory?

Comment: When I closed config properties file and run same command as you mentioned and it worked! There is not even single change in config properties. Strange! Thanks much!